# Control margins and page width in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, orchardcms

How can I make the content of an Orchard CMS website span over the whole of the browser window?

For example, the Stack Overflow website renders content almost to the edges of my browser window but the Orchard CMS has massive margins on the left and right.

Is it possible to customize the definitions of the dimensions of the Zones? For example, I would like my website to just have a Navigation Zone and a Content Zone. I want the Content zone to fill the entire browser window and the navigation bar to go across the top of the browser window from the left edge to the right edge. Just for some background, I will use a Bootstrap Carousel to display my content which is why I only want a single zone which fills the entire screen/browser window. I do not want any whitespace at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the theme you are using. It's all about the CSS styling - you're free to alter it as you see fit.

If I understand correctly, you're using some Bootstrap-based theme, right? If so, then the easiest way to achieve the desired behavior is to use `*-fluid` CSS classes for rows and container divs, as described in [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem) docs.

Comment: Thanks Piotr. That works really well. To answer your question. I have derived my theme from Bootstrap and had modified a copy of layout.cshtml to include my slide show (just in case any body is interested, I add this line to the layout to get the carousel working WorkContext.Layout.Content.Add(New.slideshow(), "5"); where slideshow is my cshtml file to define the carousel). But to get the fluid behaviour I renamed the layout to layout_backup and then copied the layout-fluid.cshtml, renamed it to layout.cshtml and made the alterations there. Now the page uses all of the browser window.